# Received empty response from Zabbix Agent at [XX.XXX.XX.XX]

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, zabbix, zabbix-api

I am trying to register zabbix agent to zabbix server but facing this error[**Received empty response from Zabbix Agent at [XX.XXX.XX.XX]. Assuming that agent dropped connection because of access permissions.**] in zabbix server UI.

I have elb top of Zabbix server and using elb dns name in zabbix agent conf file. Seems registration is happening but agent server is not active[Availability][image].

```
**conf file** 

    Server=elb end point
    ServerActive=elb end point
```

Any lead would be appreciated.

Comment: Is that a passive item and the server real address is obviously not the same as the elb address? Switch everything to active monitoring and try again.

Comment: are you able to resolve elb address from agent and hostname of zabbix agent from zabbix server? if yes then switch from zabbix agent to zabbix agent active and see latest data with more details option

Comment: @ironBishop and rohit I am able to telnet vice versa [agent and zabbix server]  on elb end point and i am not changing hostname of zabbix agent..  what do you mean via switch to passive/Active..
do i need to comment **ServerActive**?

Comment: no, I mean this https://blog.zabbix.com/zabbix-agent-active-vs-passive/9207/

Answer (score 3):

This is error from agent alowed hosts. Often when you are using the Zabbix server in docker and agent from system on the same IP.

see log file at first

```
$ cat /var/log/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.log | grep connection
```

now compare incoming connection: connection from "SOME_IP" and allowed hosts: "SOME_IPs"
example output :
`failed to accept an incoming connection: connection from "172.17.0.2" rejected, allowed hosts: "127.0.0.1`"

This is your problem. connection from 172.17.0.2 (docker) is not allowed in your zabbix_agentd.conf. You will have to edit `/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf` like this :

`Server=::ffff:127.0.0.1,172.17.0.2  ServerActive=::ffff:127.0.0.1,172.17.0.2`

Last step is restart agent

```
$ sudo systemctl restart zabbix-agent
```